# How do I finish the area around my furnace so it looks nice and isolates noise, but is still accessible?

Tags: basement

I want to put a TV right in front of my furnace and water heater. I'd like it to look reasonably finished and keep noise from the systems as low as reasonably possible.

I would love to just drywall them in, but obviously need to retain access and air flow.

Is there some way to finish the surface that would look like a wall but be reasonably easy to remove when I need to get at them? The finish level doesn't have to be perfect, but I would love it to be more than an accordion/folding door.

[image]

Comment: Is this a basement? Is there a way connect the combustion air intake on the furnace to draw from outside? Does the water heater just draw combustion air from its immediate surroundings or can it be connected to a tube to draw from outside?

Comment: Looking again at your setup I realize that the air going into the air handler is coming from a return vent probably on the floor above. Compared to my setup  this should generate much less noise and the noise should be able to be reduced by a sound absorbing partition wall. (In my setup the incoming air is entering through a grille into a plenum below the furnace. This provides a clear pathway for sound. In renovations of tract slab-on-grade houses like ours the air handler is often relocated to the attic, completely abolishing the noise.)

Answer (score 1):

I take it that these are both natural gas fired and both are currently taking their combustion air from the room. It looks like the furnace could be connected to get combustion air from the outside but the PVC tubing is not connected to a tube to draw from outside. I think you should investigate getting this done.

If you box these in to form a heater closet, you must provide vents for air from the room to move into the closet. The adequacy of vents for combustion air is regulated by law and regulations. You must contact your local construction inspection authority and see what they will require for size of a heater closet, access, and venting.

It looks to me like you are possibly not leaving enough clearance on the right side of the water heater.  I have a furnace like this, in a closet, and there is still noise. However, my Carrier NG furnace is 27 years old.

Fiberglass insulation on the outgoing duct might make a difference in sound level.

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing a vent for the water heater and seeing the intake air for the furnace is taking combustion air from the room you will be required to have a fair sized air intake to the room the total size may be close to 2 sq ft, this used to be quite common but in my county the furnace is required to be vented to the outside usually for the high effency sealed burn box type. If you can take the same path as the exhaust vent that would also reduce the area of the intake that will be required.